# Draw with core graphics only inside the circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I need to implement a XY dynamic plot - which is drawing in realtime. I have two methods, first of all I draw the circle with fill color:

```
- (void) drawCircleWithFillColorComponent:(float)value {
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat radius = MIN(center.x, center.y)-5.f;
    UIBezierPath *path = [self bezierArcWithCenter:center
                                        startAngle:0
                                          endAngle:M_PI*2
                                            radius:radius];
    [[UIColor whiteAppColor] setStroke];
    [[self colorWithValue:currentValue] setFill];
    [path setLineWidth:1.f];
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];
}
```

and than I draw a graph:

```
- (void)drawHistoryInContext:(CGContextRef)context bounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGFloat value;

    UIBezierPath *graph = [UIBezierPath new];

    for (NSUInteger counter = 0; counter < historyArray.count; counter++) {
        value = [historyArray[counter] floatValue];
        if (counter == 0) {
            [graph moveToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x+5+bounds.size.width/2/50, bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height/2-(value-1)*bounds.size.height/12)];
        } else {
            [graph addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.origin.x+5+(float)counter/(float)(50-1)*bounds.size.width/2, MAX(bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height/2-(value-1)*bounds.size.height/12,0))];
        }
    }

    [graph setLineWidth:2.f];
    [[UIColor lightBlueAppColor] setStroke];
    [graph stroke];
}
```

The problem is - the background of the graph is a circle. So I need to clip the graph inside the circle. Now the area for drawing the graph is a rectangle - sometimes the graph line displayed outside of circle borders. How can I clip the graph?

The unwanted behaviour is like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Is this a UIView subclass?

Comment: @ZeMoon yes but the circle is drawn with indents from the bounds

Comment: All I can suggest is for you to draw the line and circle on two separate views/layers and use clipping.

Comment: I assume these methods are called from within drawRect:? If so, could you post that, with some refactoring you can easily clip the context before drawing the graphline, potentially in the same method you draw the circle in.

Comment: @Henri Normak hi, can you provide some code to clip the context? I tried something but only after I draw the graphline- should I clip it before?

Comment: Clip before, then draw. Clipping affects all drawing happening afterwards, you can also save the context and then restore if you need to draw anything later that does not want to be clipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clip the context, depending on your `drawRect:` implementation. In essence, clip before drawing the graph line, then draw. Clipping affects all drawing happening afterwards, you can also save the context (using `CGContextSaveGState`) and then restore (using `CGContextRestoreGState`) if you need to draw anything later that does not want to be clipped.